# Login to web service using credentials

Tags: .net, web-services

Folks,

I have url to webservice `curl -u username:password domain/wservice/fire` and userid and password.

how can i call webservice using credentials i have? code example will be great..

Comment: i see a CURL word in your question, what do you mean? curl in .net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at [this page](http://man.ddvip.com/web/bsaspnetapp/LiB0087.html), i think it is useful, is it your answer?

Comment: this is what I did to resolve above issue curl --user name:password http://www.example.com. also used : http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html